# How to update a value automatically on a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and given a table payments with columns `expirationDate(DATE)` and `status(VARCHAR)` and I need to automatically update the status from `VALID` to `EXPIRED` when some payment expires. I need a trigger or stored procedure? And how do I make it run automatically?

Comment: Just use a computed column... or calculate it in your query.

Comment: But if you decide to use a trigger or stored procedure, have a go and ask a question when you get stuck.

Comment: And as for scheduling the update, there are many options for that, if you google you will them. SQL Server Agent is one, Windows Scheduled Tasks is another, a Windows Service is another...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a view:

```
create view v_t as 
    select (case when payment_date > dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) then 'Valid' else 'Expired' end) as status
    from t;
```